# Running pdftotext from Python

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, pdftotext

I am trying to convert a pdf document to text document using `pdftotext` software.

I need to call this application inc command prompt from python script to convert the file.

I have following code:

```
import os 
import subprocess

path = "C:\\Users\\..." 
pdffname = "pdffilename.pdf" 
txtfname = "txtfilename.txt"

subprocess.call(['pdftotext', '-layout', 
     os.path.join(path, pdffname),
     os.path.join(path, txtfname)])
```

When I run this code, I get error

```
  File "C:/Users/.../code-1.py", line 44, in <module>
    os.path.join(path, txtfname)])

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 522, in call
    return Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs).wait()

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 710, in __init__
    errread, errwrite)

  File "C:\Anaconda\lib\subprocess.py", line 958, in _execute_child
    startupinfo)

WindowsError: [Error 2] The system cannot find the file specified
```

Can you help to call `pdftotext` application from python to convert pdf to text file.

Comment: is `pdftotext` on the path? what happens for `os.call(['pdftotext'])`

Comment: issue the full command on the command line manually to see what is going on. The error suggests the file you think is there, isn't.

Comment: pass the full path to `pdftotext.exe`

Answer (score 1):

I had this same error, except with Popen. I fixed it by providing the full path to pdftotext.exe in the subprocess call. Don't forget to escape your backslashes.

I do not know much about Anaconda, and I have not tested this myself, but I believe Conda may have an issue referencing scripts on Windows: [fix references to scripts on windows](https://github.com/conda/conda-build/pull/474)

Comment: How does one 'provide the full path to pdftotext.exe' in the subprocess call? Could you please provide an example to a newbie? Thanks